# Separate subsubsections by commas in beamer table of contents

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents

I am trying to create a table of content in beamer presentations where only the subsubsections are shown separated by commas but I cannot find a way to achieve this.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Content}{}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

%---------------------------    
\section{Section 1}
\subsection{Subsection 1.1}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection 1.1.1}

\begin{frame}{Section 1}{Subsection 1.1}    
Subsubsection 1.1.1    
\end{frame}    
%---------------------------------------    
\subsubsection{Subsubsection 1.1.2}    
\begin{frame}{Section 1}{Subsection 1.1}   
Subsubsection 1.1.2    
\end{frame}    
%---------------------------------------    
\subsubsection{Subsubsection 1.1.3}   
\begin{frame}{Section 1}{Subsection 1.1}    
Subsubsection 1.1.3    
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

What I need to produce is:

```
Section 1    
  Subsection 1.1    
    Subsubsection 1.1.1, Subsubsection 1.1.2, Subsubsection 1.1.3
```

instead of:

```
Section 1    
  Subsection 1.1    
    Subsubsection 1.1.1    
    Subsubsection 1.1.2    
    Subsubsection 1.1.3
```

Many thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Although about subsections instead of subsubsections, [Beamer: Subsections in table of contents in one line](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/224247/134144) might be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These options did the job:

```
\setbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}{\par\hspace*{2em}~\inserttocsubsection\par}
\setbeamertemplate{subsubsection in toc}{\hspace*{2.5em}{~\inserttocsubsubsection}}
```